# Numbers on the wall in Cuba in "Guys and Dolls" film

Tags: analysis, guys-and-dolls-1955

In the 1955 film version of [Guys and Dolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guys_and_Dolls_%28film%29), there is a series of scenes which take place in Cuba.  One of the odd features of this sequence is a series of four digit numbers on the various walls around the area, as per the screenshot below (or [this clip](https://images.app.goo.gl/NWwDAj9ZGRV6RscaA)).

[image: Wall with numbers]

What do these represent?  Are they reflective of an actual feature of Havana, or simply something that the director put in?

Comment: If anyone has a better screenshot, that would be great - that's just the best I was able to find, and it's only mediocre.

Comment: Any chance they are automobile licence plates? There are some places/people who put these on the wall for ambience.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - It's possible - but only 4 digit plates? And they were seriously all over that area.  If that was a thing in Havana at the time, then that would count as "Reflective of an actual feature" and make for a good answer.

Comment: They might also be intended to suggest a numbers den (or "bolito," as it would have been called in Havana).

Comment: @MichaelStern - That would definitely fit the theme of the movie, since it's all about gamblers.

Comment: Seem to be house or apartment numbers.
But ... ??

Comment: There have been 4-digit license plates, see lowdigittags.com

Comment: Here’s another example. Definitely not license plates! https://goo.gl/images/hD6m2M

Comment: @JohnP - Good idea. Thanks for the static capture, and I've just replaced my original very dark image with it.

Comment: @Bobson - They aren't license plates. I found a few web examples of old plates from that era (1955) online, and they all had words of some sort.

Comment: Could the numbers be some derivative of [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101584/why-is-havana-covered-in-5-digit-numbers-in-our-man-in-havana/101586?r=SearchResults&s=1|33.6561#101586)?

Comment: @Jeeped - That looks like it's almost certainly it.  Mystery solved!  Want to write it into an answer I can (finally) accept?

Comment: Unfortunately, I learned about the Cuban lottery numbers myself from that linked Q&A and don't really have anything more to contribute.

Answer (score 2):

They’re lottery numbers - they’re also prevalent in ‘Our Man in Havana’ based on Graham Greene’s novel. It was part of the superstitious culture of Cuba that people would look for auspicious or lucky numbered tickets being sold, so vendors would prominently post potentially favourable numbers they had for sale.